# how do I test constructor in java which refers to current object?

Tags: java, sonarqube

My code doesn't meet the sonarqube code coverage the following piece of constructor says it needs test in sonarqube, I have written the following code to test it but it is not covering the code? can some one help me where I am going wrong?

```
@Test
public void OrderBuilderIT() {
    errorQueue.equals("amq:ORDER.T.SYSTEM.ERROR");
}

public OrderBuilder(String errorQueue) {
    this.errorQueue = errorQueue;
}
```

the code does not seem to be covered

Comment: Is your unit test in the same class as the real code? That's unusual to say the least. I'd also *strongly* advise you not to write methods with the same name as the class itself.

Comment: no its in different test class

Comment: Then please make that *much* clearer in the question. What do you expect `errorQueue` to refer to, if you're not actually in `OrderBuilder`? Please provide a [mcve], because at the moment your question is very unclear.

Comment: I just edited the code its in test class

Comment: Which is the constructor that isn't covered?

Comment: It's still *far* from a complete example. You've posted a constructor and a method, with no indication of which classes they're in, what they're meant to do, any field declarations etc.

Comment: Also note that just calling `equals` on a string doesn't actually assert anything.

Comment: If you say that `OrderBuilder(String errorQueue)` is the constructor that isn't covered, in your test you should call code which can instantiate `OrderBuilder` with the particular constructor.

Comment: The test should test any public method in such a way that it instantiates `OrderBuilder` with the constructor `OrderBuilder(String errorQueue)` and also tests the logic of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are trying to test the constructor call for the class with the error queue field value that you are passing while constructing and expecting the same value to be asserted. Actually, your check does nothing in terms of an assertion.

Below is an assumption that you may be trying to achieve. Also, should cover your sonar issue.

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
public class SomeConstructorTest {

private OrderBuilder orderBuilder;

 @Test
public void orderBuilderTestWithIncorrectErrorQueueMessage(){
    String expected = "amq:ORDER.T.SYSTEM.ERROR";
    String errorQueue = "dummyString";
    orderBuilder = new OrderBuilder(errorQueue);
    assertThat(expected, is(errorQueue)); // should fail if you are asserting string content
}

}
```

Comment: but when I try the above test in the assertThat I am getting an error as cannot resolve method assertThat(java.lang.string, com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.propertystate) im using the following imports        import static com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.PropertyState.is;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Java6Assertions.assertThat; can you please let me know if I have wrong imports ?

Comment: Try the imports that I have updated based on your request.